# Populating a secondary column of a gridview based on primary dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, sql-server-2012

I'm currently having a coding theory challenge (ASP/C#/SQL) at the moment and this question is more of a need to talk it out with the masses and hopefully get a better picture of how I need to approach this puzzle.

Right now I have an operational `Gridview` (SQL 2012/.Net 4) that can show/manipulate data.

The gridview I have is a listing of past ice cream sales that is missing the sizes of ice cream containers sold.  I need to go through a sizable list and put a container size and the amount that each container holds for a bunch of records.

For example, here's a list of containers:

```
Cup - 8 oz
Pint - 16 oz
Quart - 32 oz
Gallon - 128 oz
```

The container names are in one dropdown list.  The assigning and saving of the container names works without any issues.  However, the challenge I'm wokring on is once the selection of the container is named I need to assign the ounces of each container automatically in a secondary column in the same table/gridview.

In short, the expected behavior is that once the container name, let's use Pint for this example, is selected in the dropdown of column A automatically 16 oz would appear in Column B and then can be saved.

My questions are these:

1) Would it be better to use a secondary dropdown menu that has (using the example from above) the ounces of each container already assigned?  Or would it be better to just have the list of sizes available to be pulled from in a separate table.
2) If I need to add more containers/ounces to the list what would be the best way to approach this programatically?  Let's say I wanted to add something called a Super Quart that is 64 ounces in size should I make it editable so that the end user can enter it or should I just do it behind the scenes?
3) Am I missing something else here?

I'm really stumped on how to approach this puzzle.  I'd like to learn how to approach this so If you can provide some explanations on how to approach this that would greatly be appreeciated.  If something needs more elaboration, please do not hesitate to ask.

Here's some of the coding examples I've been looking at.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53559/Accessing-a-DropDownList-inside-a-GridView
http://forums.asp.net/t/1229978.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1513442.aspx

Comment: If you're going to be keeping additional data on each "size", especially if that data is not standardized (e.g., the "superquart"), then you should have a table for the sizes.

Comment: I think your question is a little broad, and might not get good answers here.  It's possible that you could get help on [codereview.se], if you posted your existing code, and asked for specific improvements.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I just looked at Code Review and these kinds of questions are not allowed there.